# Logical error with the || operator?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

A part of my program (I can add more details if necessary) contains this line:

```
if((e->start->explored = false) || (e->end->explored = false)){
   //do action...
 }
```

This is part of a graph algorithm, where e is a directed edge with incident vertices "start" and "end." I would like the 'action' to happen if at least one of the incident vertices of e is unexplored, but this logic appears to be faulty. Although I used a small example and verified that, indeed, the start and end vertices of my edges were unexplored to start with, my overall function is going into an infinite loop.

So then I tested it like this:

```
  if((e->start->explored = false) || (e->end->explored = false)){
       //do action...
     } 

  else cout << "FAIL";
```

...and, of course, it printed a screen of "FAIL." What is my logic error here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're assigning `false` to your properties instead of testing them against `false`. This is a mistake often made, and quite hard to debug. Change your `=` assignment operator to the equality operator `==`:

```
if((e->start->explored == false) || (e->end->explored == false)) {
    // Do action...
} else {
    cout << "FAIL";
}
```

---

Instead of comparing the values to `false`, it's clearer to use the `!` not operator instead. The inner brackets are done away with, too:

```
if(!e->start->explored || !e->end->explored) {
    // Do action...
} else {
    cout << "FAIL";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As the others have expounded you accidentally used assignment instead of comparison. However, the real solution is not to compare at all:

Comparing bool values to literals `true` and `false` is nonsensical!

Instead, write:

```
if(! e->start->explored || ! e->end->explored)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used the assignment operator = not the comparison operator ==.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning values here:

```
if((e->start->explored = false) || (e->end->explored = false)){
```

Should be:

```
if((e->start->explored == false) || (e->end->explored == false)){
```